# How to write a jest test that will pass if return value is array of objects?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm learning unit tests, and I've covered pretty much the basics.

Now I'm trying to test my scraper. My initial function involves multiple scrapers, but i wanted to check if each scraper works properly. The output of the test (to test be successful) should be if the return has an `[{},{},...,{}]` - array of objects. I really cant know what is inside of the objects(data is always different), but it's always a array of objects.

Now what my question is: How to properly do this? I've tried in multiple ways, and my test always fails.
Closes that I've been is this solution:

```
const santScraper = require('../scraping/scrapers/sant-scraper');

test('Does scraper works properly', async () => {
  await expect(santScraper(1)).toBe({});
});
```

But my output is this:

```
FAIL  tests/santScraper.test.js
  × Does scraper works properly (20 ms)

  ● Does scraper works properly

    expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    - Expected  - 1
    + Received  + 1

    - Object {}
    + Promise {}

      2 |
      3 | test('Does scraper works properly', async () => {
    > 4 |   await expect(santScraper(1)).toBe({});
        |                                ^
      5 | });
      6 |

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/santScraper.test.js:4:32)

Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       1 failed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.016 s
Ran all test suites.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I really dont know what is pointing to.

Also here is my scraper:

```
//const data_functions = require('../data-functions/data-functions');
const axios = require('axios'); //npm package - promise based http client
const cheerio = require('cheerio'); //npm package - used for web-scraping in server-side implementations
const data_functions = require('../data-functions/data-functions');

//santScaper function which as paramater needs count which is sent in the scraping-service file.
const santScraper = async (count) => {
  const url = `https://www.sant.ba/pretraga/prodaja-1/tip-2/cijena_min-20000/stranica-${count}`;

  const santScrapedData = [];
  try {
    await load_url(url, santScrapedData);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

//Function that does loading URL part of the scraper, and starting of process for fetching raw data.
const load_url = async (url, santScrapedData) => {
  await axios.get(url).then((response) => {
    const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    get_article_html_nodes($).each((index, element) => {
      process_single_article($, index, element, santScrapedData);
    });

    data_functions.mergeData(santScrapedData);
    return santScrapedData; //this is where I return array of objects
  });
};

// Part where raw html data is fetched but in div that we want.
const get_article_html_nodes = ($) => {
  return $('div[class="col-xxs-12 col-xss-6 col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-lg-4"]');
};

//Here is all logic for getting data that we want, from the raw html.
const process_single_article = ($, index, element, santScrapedData) => {
  const getLink = $(element).find('a[class="re-image"]').attr('href');
  const getDescription = $(element).find('a[class="title"]').text();
  const getPrice = $(element)
    .find('div[class="prices"] > h3[class="price"]')
    .text()
    .replace(/\.| ?KM$/g, '')
    .replace(',', '.');
  const getPicture = $(element).find('img').attr('data-original');
  const getSquaremeters = $(element)
    .find('span[class="infoCount"]')
    .first()
    .text()
    .replace(',', '.')
    .split('m')[0];
  const pricepersquaremeter =
    parseFloat(getPrice) / parseFloat(getSquaremeters);

  santScrapedData[index] = {
    id: getLink.substring(42, 46),
    link: getLink,
    description: getDescription,
    price: Math.round(getPrice),
    picture: getPicture,
    squaremeters: Math.round(getSquaremeters),
    pricepersquaremeter: Math.round(pricepersquaremeter),
  };
};

module.exports = santScraper;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `typeof` in this case like so :-

```
test('Does scraper works properly', async () => {
  await expect(typeof santScraper(1)).toBe('object');
});
```

Although if it's always the `Promise` object you want to check against, you can get more specific using `instanceof` like so :-

```
test('Does scraper works properly', async () => {
  await expect(santScraper(1) instanceof Promise).toBe(true);
});
```